# How do I Emulate/Debug Windows CE 5.0 applications in C#?

Tags: visual-studio, compact-framework, .net-2.0, embedded, platform-builder

Here's my problem. I'm currently trying to develop a .Net Compact Framework 2.0 application (in C#) to a Windows CE 5.0 device.

Firstly: How do I debug/emulate the application in Visual Studio 2008 ? I doesn't mean debugging an application already deployed on the device, but debugging the version on my desktop. I have limited or no access to the prototype device.

Secondly: How do I integrate it with the OS image made by Platform Builder for Windows CE 5.0 ? Do I need to ?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so thanks everyone for the quick and nice answers. Although I've found my own solution yours may be as valid as mine.

Basically what I didn't tell you (because I didn't really know it either) is that I didn't actually need to emulate the OS, I only needed to work with the framework. I found the best way to "emulate" such situation [here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2005/01/deploy-to-my-computer.html).

Also, I found that the easiest way to deploy the application to the device is to use ActiveSync and I found [just the right (MSDN) article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446504.aspx) for it.

Ctacke: It's probably due to my only learning this type of development, I somehow made an error while creating/installing "my own SDK" so the Visual Studio stopped functioning properly. But of course some digging made that go away. Thanks anyway. I liked the idea of developing with a testing device, unfortunately the company I work for already picked a device but they couldn't issue me a prototype for development purposes yet.

Frans, I haven't found your CE simulator, but I'm pretty sure that I didn't look for it enough so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.  One would be to install the Emulator BSP, roll your own emulator image, build a custom SDK and install it, then debug targeting that emulator.  It's fairly simple to do.

That said, I still wouldn't do it.  A far better option is to just go buy a cheap WinCE device like an [eBox 4300 jump start kit](http://www.wdlsystems.com/modperl/view_services.cgi?r=detail&prod_num=1EB43SK&aisle_id=1061).  It's way easier, faster and and more reliable to target real iron.

As for integrating the app, it's like any other.  Make sure you have the CF component included in your OS design from the Catalog, then add your app to your PROJECT.BIB (and REG and/or DAT files if needed) and run makeimg again.

Comment: I have to agree that working with a real device beats the pants off of using any of the emulators (that I've used anyway).

Comment: I've been using emulators since about CE 2.0, and while they are way, way, way better than they used to be (they're now usable and pretty stable), I find that connecting to a device over ethernet is just faster than the emulator transport.  It doesn't make logical sense that it is, but the build/deploy/debug/break/fix cycle is shorter with an external device on ethernet than a local emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the emulator which comes with the CE SDK. You can use that directly from vs.net, and it has all win CE features. DEbugging then works on that emulator, so you can step through your code as if it's running on a device.

Comment: There is no CE emulator that ships with said mythical "CE SDK".

Comment: But there is a WM5 SDK that includes an emulator.  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=DC6C00CB-738A-4B97-8910-5CD29AB5F8D9&displaylang=en

Comment: Not a "Windows CE 5.0 device" emulator.  Huge difference.

Comment: @ctacke
The question was teh OS, not the device. If he wants to emulate stone-age tech, perhaps he should use vs.net 2003, which comes with the CE 5.x emulator. 

I also fail to understand why the TS wants to emulate 5.0, which is clearly an old OS from the POV of Microsoft, i.o.w.: with vs.net 2008, use the 6.x emulator (downloadable separately) or if you really are up to it, re-use the emu from 2003. 

I also find your wording particular insulting. 'mythical sdk' ? I was just trying to help out. Thanks for giving me the stimulance to spend more of my time here...

Comment: Hey Frans. You're entirely right. I do want to emulate "stone-age tech" because that "old OS from the POV of Microsoft" will fit right into some "stone age hardware". But thanks anyway.

Comment: I called it stone-age tech because MS had to make a lot of progress at that time so v5 is OK-ish but nowadays one could better opt for the newer offerings, also because you talk about a prototype, so IMHO new hardware. (and you use 2008)

Anyway, if you want to have the proper tools right away, use an older version of vs.net, e.g. 2005, which comes with the tools for ce 5.0: http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehall/archive/2005/12/20/505891.aspx
It's a bit confusing, as MS changed names from windows CE to windows mobile at that time as well.